# Error ITMS-90086: "Missing 64-bit support" && Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, arm64

I am trying to update an iOS app through XCode and Application Loader, but I always get this error:

> ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code."

So I applied some solutions founded here in **Stack Overflow**, now my configuration is like this:

- **Standard architectures** (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
- **Base SDK** Latest iOS (iOS 9.2)
- **Build Active Architecture Only** YES (*I also tried with NO*)
- **Supported Platforms** iOS
- **Valid Architectures** armv7 armv7s arm64

After I did the configuration above to implement the arm64 architecture, I having troubles with some libraries:

> ERROR: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: (Some libraries)...

These libraries are already in the **Link Binary With Libraries** section. Needless to say, that if I remove the configuration with architectures, the code runs great, but I can't update it to the apple platform.

My deployment target is 7.0, but I also having this problem with the target 6.0.

My XCode version is 7.2.

Do some one knows a possible solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Can please check if you any dependencies frameworks or two framework having the same classes or with class name so the while you build the app this may one of your reasons to get undefined symbols. This also may be the reason that the framework which you are used in your project many not support any specific architecture. Please check it.